Container Freezes After Deployment and Requires Manual Restart to Function Normally
I am experiencing an issue where my containers, deployed using Podman, enters a "freeze" state immediately after deployment. The container does not function as expected until I manually restart it. After the restart, the container works perfectly fine. I am using Azure DevOps for my CI/CD pipeline.
Details:
CI/CD Pipeline: The deployment is part of an Azure DevOps pipeline that performs the following steps:

Build the backend application using the specified build process.
Build a Docker (Podman) image for the backend service.
Push the Docker image to Azure Container Registry (ACR).
Deploy the new container on an Azure VM using Podman.

Deployment Process:

The pipeline pulls the latest Docker image from ACR.
It then runs the container using Podman on port 5000.
A check is performed to ensure the container is running.

CI/CD Pipline:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - mb/gunicorn

pool:
  name: General

variables:
  - group: PQP_Variable

jobs:
  - job: BuildBackend
    displayName: 'Build Backend'
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Listing built images..."
          podman images
        displayName: 'List Podman Images'

      - script: |
          echo "Removing old versions of the image..."
          podman images --format "{{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep 'pqp_be_gunicorn' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'podman rmi -f {} || true'
        displayName: 'Remove Old Versions of the Image'

      - script: |
          echo "Building backend Podman image..."
          export IMAGE_TAG=$(date -u -d "+2 hours" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
          podman build -t pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG} .
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Image built successfully"
            echo "IMAGE_TAG=${IMAGE_TAG}" > image_tag.txt
          else
            echo "Image build failed"
            exit 1
          fi
        displayName: 'Build Backend Podman Image'

      - script: |
          echo "Logging into Azure Container Registry..."
          podman login -u $(AZURE_ACR_USERNAME) -p $(AZURE_ACR_PASSWORD) pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Failed to login to Azure Container Registry"
            exit 1
          fi
        displayName: 'Login to Azure Container Registry'

      - script: |
          echo "Tagging the image..."
          export IMAGE_TAG=$(cat image_tag.txt | cut -d '=' -f2)
          podman tag pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG} pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG}
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Failed to tag the image"
            exit 1
          fi
        displayName: 'Tag Backend Podman Image'

      - script: |
          echo "Pushing the image to Azure Container Registry..."
          export IMAGE_TAG=$(cat image_tag.txt | cut -d '=' -f2)
          podman push pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG}
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Failed to push the image"
            exit 1
          fi
        displayName: 'Push Backend Podman Image to Azure Container Registry'

      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'AzurePQPTest'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            set -e
            echo 'Logging in to Azure...'
            az login --service-principal -u $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID) -p $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET) --tenant $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)

            echo 'Logging in to ACR...'
            podman login pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io -u $(AZURE_ACR_USERNAME) -p $(AZURE_ACR_PASSWORD)

            export IMAGE_TAG=$(cat image_tag.txt | cut -d '=' -f2)
            CONTAINER_NAME="pqp-backend-gunicorn-${IMAGE_TAG}"
            echo "Pulling the latest backend image..."
            podman pull pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG}

            echo "Running new backend container with name ${CONTAINER_NAME} on port 5001..."
            podman run -d --name=${CONTAINER_NAME} --restart=always -p 5001:5000 \
              -e FLASK_ENV=$(FLASK_ENV) -e ES_TOKEN=$(ES_TOKEN) \
              pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG}

            echo "Waiting for the new backend container to initialize..."
            sleep 10

            echo "Checking if the new backend container is running..."
            if podman ps --filter "name=${CONTAINER_NAME}" --filter "status=running" --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -q "^${CONTAINER_NAME}$"; then
              echo "New backend container is running."
              echo "Stopping and removing old backend container..."
              podman stop pqp-backend-gunicorn || true
              podman rm pqp-backend-gunicorn || true
              echo "Renaming new container to pqp-backend-gunicorn..."
              podman rename ${CONTAINER_NAME} pqp-backend-gunicorn
              echo "Mapping new container to original port 5000..."
              podman stop pqp-backend-gunicorn
              podman rm pqp-backend-gunicorn
              podman run -d --name pqp-backend-gunicorn --restart=always -p 5000:5000 \
                -e FLASK_ENV=$(FLASK_ENV) -e ES_TOKEN=$(ES_TOKEN) \
                pdspqptestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/pqp_be_gunicorn:${IMAGE_TAG}

              echo "Cleaning up old images in ACR, keeping the last 5..."
              REPO="pqp_be_gunicorn"
              IMAGES=$(az acr repository show-tags --name pdspqptestcontainerregistry --repository $REPO --orderby time_desc --output tsv | tail -n +6)
              for IMAGE in $IMAGES; do
                az acr repository delete --name pdspqptestcontainerregistry --image $REPO:$IMAGE --yes
              done

              echo "Cleaning up old images locally, excluding the current image..."
              podman images --format "{{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep 'pqp_be' | grep -v "${IMAGE_TAG}" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'podman rmi -f {} || true'
            else
              echo "New backend container failed to start. Exiting."
              podman logs ${CONTAINER_NAME}
              podman stop ${CONTAINER_NAME}
              exit 1
            fi
        displayName: 'Deploy Backend Container to Azure VM and Clean Up Old Images in ACR'

In the deployment process, we tried checking the health status of the container by pinging it with curl. While the container's services seemed to be running normally, the health check with curl ended with an error. After completing the health check, the container enters the "freeze" state where it does not respond until it is manually restarted. Once restarted, the container works without any issues.


"the health check with curl ended with an error" - What's the specific error? 2. Did the same pipeline work before? Or it keeps having the same problem? 3. To narrow down the issue, deploy the container on your local machine and check whether there is the same problem or not.


Hi  Ziyang Liu-MSFT, thank you for your response. To address your questions:

The specific error from the health check using curl is "Connection refused". This happens consistently right after deployment.
The pipeline has been consistently experiencing this issue; it has never worked without the manual restart step.
I have deployed the container locally  and it works fine without any freeze issues.



“I have deployed the container locally and it works fine without any freeze issues.”  - Is this local machine in your agent pool named “General”? Or it's your Azure VM mentioned here "Deploy the new container on an Azure VM using Podman.". Or your Azure VM is a self-hosted agent in agent pool “General”? 2. Are you running the same scripts locally as in the pipeline?


I did not run the full pipeline on my local machine. Instead, I manually pulled the image from the Azure Container Registry and ran the container using Docker. When I did this locally, the container worked fine without any freeze issues.
This suggests that the issue might be related to the specific environment or setup on the Azure VM rather than the container image or the deployment scripts themselves.
To further diagnose, I will try setting up a work agent on my local computer and run the full pipeline to see if the issue persists.

I agree with you, set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run the pipeline using it. If it works, then the issue is related to your agent in "General" pool. If it doesn't, maybe you need to check your Azure VM.

Thank you for your assistance! I set up a new agent pool and agent with all necessary permissions, but the issue persists. I also tried setting up a new environment on my local computer using WSL (Ubuntu on Windows). For this purpose, I created another agent pool and agent called "Local," and the deployment works correctly without freezing after deployment. The only difference is that in my local environment, I used Docker instead of Podman.

I am not an expert of Podman. But according to your update, it seems there are something to do with Podman.
